# Performing unit conversions in Spotlight

Tags: macos, spotlight

Is there a way to perform unit conversions from within Spotlight?  For example I want to convert 1 ft^3 to cm^3 in spotlight.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really any way to customize the Spotlight menu or add features to it.

I know it would be nicer to display the results inline, but it doesn't take that long to search with Google either:

[image]

There are some Alfred extensions that use [Google's calculator API](http://texasexpat.net/2011/10/convert-for-alfred) or [Wolfram Alpha's API](http://jdfwarrior.tumblr.com/post/13844480373/wolfram), but they display the results as notifications, so you can't copy them as text.

Comment: Apple's Calculator app has that ability and it should be implemented into Spotlight.